# How to DataTrigger for Parent element from child element condition

Tags: wpf, xaml

Trying to finding way for solve the following problem.

My goal is:
 If some child-element in Button does not contain the text, then disabled the parent button.

So, what exactly I'm trying do:

Create a button:

```
 <Button  Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" >
     <TextBlock>
         <Run Name="TxtElement1" Text=""/>
     </TextBlock>
 </Button>
 <Button  Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" >
     <TextBlock>
        <Run Name="TxtElement2" Text="some text 1"/>
     </TextBlock>
 </Button>
 <Button  Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" >
     <TextBlock>
        <Run Name="TxtElement3" Text="some text 2"/>
     </TextBlock>
 </Button>
```

Now create a style with trigger:

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=TxtElement1, Path=Text}" Value="">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=TxtElement2, Path=Text}" Value="">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=TxtElement3, Path=Text}" Value="">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

So, in result I got: *All ToggleButtons is disabled*. 
But me need disable only Button when property Text in Run child-element is empty

Maybe I'm use radically wrong approach.. Thanks for any attention.

Comment: Tbh, this makes totally no sense... Why would you even style your Buttons like this? Use the Button's `Content` and do a self-binding

Comment: In my case I'm use few source for button Content. Look's like:  `<TextBlock >
               <Run Text="Some text"/>
               <Run Name="TxtElement3" Text="{Binding SomeTextFromVM}"/>
            </TextBlock>`

Comment: Okay. Good for you. Doesnt change the fact that its really strange and that this wont work. The Style is defined **before** your buttons and has therefore no knowledge about the Buttons' content (Wich you should really use for some simple text). A workaround might be an `ControlTemplate` or Behavior or CodeBehind. But with plain XAML you're gonna have a bad time

Comment: Of course in my real XAML Style written before Buttons. Sorry for confusion. You can reveal some details how I can use ControlTemplate for solved my problem? I will be very grateful

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not to make things complicated.Styles are applied to button before setting up data. Bind your VMSource to Button's Content Property Directly. Then Use Loaded Event to do some operations( in this case enable/disable. See snip below.

```
<Button  Loaded="Button_Loaded" Content="" />
<Button  Loaded="Button_Loaded" Content="some text 1" />
<Button  Loaded="Button_Loaded" Content="some text 2"/>
```

Below would be your Button_Loaded Event.

```
private void Button_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button _button = (Button)sender;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_button.Content.ToString()))
        _button.IsEnabled = false;
}
```

Since Loaded is fired only after Text is Updated, you will always see button disabled since there is no content.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

Wow man... You realy got my brain smokey.

I came to one really ugly solution, that might handle your stubborn wish to use `Run`.

**XAML**

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self} , Path=Content, Converter={StaticResource Converter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

**Converter**

```
public class MyConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null) return true; //No Content at all
        var block = value as TextBlock;               
        if (block != null)
        {
            block.Loaded += (sender, args) => //Inlines are only availilable if Control has loaded
            {
                var loadedBlock = sender as TextBlock;
                var inlineCount = loadedBlock.Inlines.Count == 0;
                if (!inlineCount)
                {
                    var runs = loadedBlock.Inlines.OfType<Run>();
                    foreach (var run in runs.Where(run => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(run.Text)))
                    {
                        (loadedBlock.Parent as Button).IsEnabled = true;
                    }
                }
            };
            return string.IsNullOrEmpty(block.Text);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
<Button Content="Click me" Width="80" Height="20" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}"/>
<Button Width="80" Height="20" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}"/>
<Button Width="80" Height="20" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}">
    <TextBlock Foreground="Red">
        <Run Name="TxtElement3" Text="some text 2"/>
    </TextBlock>
</Button>
<Button Width="80" Height="20" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" >
    <TextBlock>
        <Run Text=""/>
    </TextBlock>
</Button>
<Button Width="80" Height="20" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" >
    <TextBlock>
        <Run Text=""/>
        <Run Text="Some other Text"></Run>
    </TextBlock>
</Button>
```

**IMPOPRTANT**

I highly! recommend you to **NOT USE THIS SOLUTION** (even it works).
Instead use the Content of the Button and just put your stuff there if you have just plain Text.